# php and html insert picture in the data base

Tags: php, html

i'm creating a member area ! i included a condition in order to insert a profile picture for the member 
it dosen't show any errors ! The problem is that the picture cannot be inserted into the base what should i do ?

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label >Pseudo : </label>
    <input name="newpseudo" type="text" placeholder="pseudo" value="<?php echo $user['pseudo']; ?>" /><br/><br/>
    <label>email : </label>
    <input name="newmail" type="email" placeholder="mail" value="<?php echo $user['mail'];?>" /><br/><br/>
    <label>mot de passe  : </label>
    <input name="newmdp1" type="password" placeholder="mot de passe"/><br/><br/>
    <label>confirmation du mot de passe : </label>
    <input name="newmdp2" type="password" placeholder="confirmation du mot de passe"/><br/><br/>
    <label>avatar :</label>
    <input type="file" name="avatar"></input><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="formedition" value="Mettre a jour mon profil !">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php    
if(isset($_FILES['avatar']) and !empty($_FILES['avatar']['name']))
{
    $tailleMax = 2097152;
    $extensionsValides = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
    if($_FILES['avatar']['size'] <= $tailleMax)
    {
        $extensionUpload = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['avatar']['name'], '.'), 1));
        if(in_array($extensionUpload, $extensionsValides))
        {

            $chemin = "membres/avatars/".$_SESSION['id'].".".$extensionUpload;
            $resultat = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $chemin);
            if($resultat)
            {
                $updateAvatar = $bdd -> prepare('UPDATE membres SET avatar = ? WHERE id=?');
                $updateAvatar -> execute(array(
                    'avatar' => $_SESSION['id'].".".$extensionUpload , 
                    'id ' => $_SESSION['id']
                    ));
                header("location:profil.php?id=" . $_SESSION['id']);
            }
            else
            {
                $msg = " erreur lors de l'importation de votre photo de profil ";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $msg =" votre photo de profil doit etre au forme de jpeg png gif ou jpg";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "votre photo de profil ne doit pas depasse 2 MO ! ";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Mohamed, please don't do that. Never store a picture in a database if you can store it in another place.  Read/write to a DB is always slower than a filesystem. Your DB backups grow to be huge and more time consuming and finally access to the files now requires going through your app and DB layers.

Comment: You shouldn't save the image itself in your database, but its reference or path to find it in your filesystem.

Comment: Yes i just inserted the path but it dosen't appear in the database !

Comment: What path you inserted ?

Comment: Change it to `'avatar' => "membres/avatars/".$_SESSION['id'].".".$extensionUpload , `

Comment: `$updateAvatar->execute($_SESSION['id'].".".$extensionUpload,$_SESSION['id']);` ?

Comment: ^I see, wrong placeholders there.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but rather a series of steps you can take to QUICKLY solve this problem yourself.

"Divide and conquer". Instead of troubleshooting the entire app, all at once, break it up into smaller pieces (temporarily, for testing) and troubleshoot each piece.

First, copy your PHP code into a separate file - `test.php` or some such. Hard code some information to replace the data received in the $_POSTs, and run the file. Does the data go into the database? Probably not. Fix that and copy the fix into your original PHP file. Is everything fixed now?

If not, then copy your original PHP file and call it `test2.php`. Now, instead of putting the data into the database, just echo it out to the screen. What do you see?

Create a log file and write messages into it at various points in the code. *Because PHP does not usually abort with an error message -- it just silently stops -- you need to give yourself some "eyes" to see what's going on:*

```
$handle = fopen('__logfile.txt','a');
$line = 'Got to here 01' . "\n";
fwrite($handle, $line);
fclose($handle);
```